# Проблема в расчете направления векторов

Tags: python, математика, вектор

Пытаюсь написать функцию, которая будет рассчитывать корректный угол вектора относительно положительной оси ординат. Столкнулся с проблемой: к примеру между вектором, лежащем на оси `y (0, 1)` и вектором `(2, 0)` я получаю 90 градусов - и это правильно, то если найти угол между `(0, 1)` и `(-2, 0)` - тоже получится 90 градусов, с одной стороны это логично, потому что формула ищет кратчайший угол. Но мне требуется получить не 90, а 270 градусов, так как мне необходимо задавать точное направление на плоскости для объекта. Вот фрагмент моего кода:

```py
def calculate_yaw(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    null_vector = [[0, 0], [x1 - x2, y1 - y2]]
    cos_alpha = null_vector[1][0] / math.sqrt(null_vector[1][0]**2 + null_vector[1][1]**2)
    arc_cos_in_grad = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_alpha))
    print(f"arccos: {arc_cos_in_grad}")
    return arc_cos_in_grad
```

Сперва я конвертирую вектор в нулевой, затем нахожу косинус угла, а потом перевожу в градусы. Но из-за того, что я получаю кратчайший угол между вектором и осью - у меня возникает большая проблема. Может быть есть какая нибудь другая формула или мне нужно сделать 2 расчета, сначала относительно оси `y`, а потом оси `x` и отталкиваться от этих значений, попутно сравнивая их результаты ?

Comment: `Сперва я конвертирую вектор в нулевой,` - наверное единичный имелся в виду

Comment: @insolor, нет, нормализацию я убрал. Мне она не особо важна была. А вот когда у меня вектор вида [[2, 3], [5, 2]] - это не очень удобно, и я сдвигал его так, чтобы его начало было в точке 0, 0. То есть приводил к виду: [0, 0], [3, -1]

Comment: Что-то с терминами не то, [[2, 3], [5, 2]]  - это уже не вектор, а матрица. Не очень понятен смысл операции, больше похоже что вы разницу векторов во второй строке этой матрицы получаете просто.

Comment: Я бы попробовал делать через матрицу поворота "наоборот" - привести оба вектора к единичным, потом как бы считать, что второй вектор получен поворотом первого, построить матрицу поворота и найти синусы и косинусы поворота. По синусу и косинусу можно по идее однозначно восстановить угол (по часовой стрелке был поворот или против часовой стрелки). Если угол отрицательный, то вычесть его из 360.

Comment: @insolor Почему же не вектор? Разве не бывает векторов, у которых начало не в нулевой точке? [[x1, y1][x2, y2]]. К примеру такой можно получить если взять 2 точки двух разных объектов на плоскости и взять за начальную точку координаты первого объекта, а за конечную координаты второго

Comment: @insolor, что касается терминов - то я спорить не буду, "нулевой вектор" - это моя отсебятина, но по смыслу я думаю понятно, что я имел в виду

Comment: У <s>портянки</s> векторов нет начала, у векторов есть концы, т.е. координаты "конца". Либо направление и длина (что тоже на самом деле координаты конца). Вектор не начинается в какой-то точке, его можно поместить в любую точку пространства, его координаты не изменятся. Если у вас две пары координат (начало и конец), то это уже не вектор, а отрезок, начало и конец которого задаются двумя векторами.

Comment: @insolor, вы опытней, вам виднее)

Comment: Это не опыт, это остаточные знания из курса по линейной алгебре и аналитической геометрии (остаточные знания в отличие от опыта не растут, а только убывают, если их не использовать))

Comment: @insolor, пусть так) В любом случае спасибо за информацию)

Comment: @insolor, "школьный" вектор - отрезок. У него есть начало и конец. Если "школьный" вектор начинается в нуле, его называют радиус-вектор. Когда вы попадаете в институт радиус-вектор становится просто вектором, "школьный" вектор исчезает совсем. Если он вам нужен, представьте его как пару (радиус) векторов. Вектора бывают разные.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy для меня наверное школа - это "давно и неправда", больше 15 лет прошло все-таки). В школе вроде бы и объясняли вектор как отрезок с началом в нуле (это как бы норм объяснение), но я не помню такого, чтобы говорили что вектор - это то же самое что отрезок. Помню, что объяснялись какие-то из операций с векторами, как минимум сложение и вычитание, и вроде бы скалярное произведение, графически при сложении один из векторов началом "приставлялся" к концу другого, но от этого перемещения у вектора не появлялись координаты начала.

Comment: @insolor, если выражаться более корректно, под вектором из нуля я подразумевал вычисление координат вектора по двум точкам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [atan2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2) чтобы восстановить направление вектора (`null_vector`). Дальше вам нужно будет привести результат в нужный диапазон:

```
import math


def direction(x, y):
    return math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))


def test(x, y):
    print(x, y, direction(x, y))


test(1, 0)
test(1, 1)
test(0, 1)
test(-1, 1)
test(-1, 0)
test(-1, -1)
test(0, -1)
test(1, -1)
```

> ```
> $ python directions.py
> 1 0 0.0
> 1 1 45.0
> 0 1 90.0
> -1 1 135.0
> -1 0 180.0
> -1 -1 -135.0
> 0 -1 -90.0
> 1 -1 -45.0
> ```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, очень выручили